# Adding a static CMS block to the wishlists right sidebar?

Tags: magento, block

I am trying to add a static cms block called "mytest" to the right sidebar of the wishlist. This is what I added to wishlist.xml inside the wishlist_index_index handle:

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="cms/block" name="mytest">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>mytest</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

It wont appear though. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try block type as "core/template" and recheck. (Cache refreshed).

Comment: Same, it wont show up ...

Comment: Can you try adding it outside wishlist_index_index.

Comment: I did, in the default handle, wont show up. I tried adding the same code to the catalog.xml and it shows up. So the code itself seems to be ok.

Comment: Can you cross check your layout file whether you are calling this block at proper location or not.

Comment: I think I am because removing other blocks works like a charm. Maybe I can change it in the phtml directly? Where would I do that?

Comment: THEME/template/customer/wishlist.phtml

Comment: Its just not working, any other ideas?